# Setting localStorage on click of <Link /> - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-router-v4

I am trying something childish, but it should work after all.

I have to links in my page.

```
<Link to="/detail" className="table-details-btn" onClick={this.addlocalid('J8')}></Link>
<Link to="/detail" className="table-details-btn" onClick={this.addlocalid('E8')}></Link>
```

And on click i want to set localStorage by given value. e.g. J8, E8

```
addlocalid(localid){
  console.log("Setting VUID To:"+localid);
  localStorage.setItem('vuserid', localid);
}
```

But it console it displays:

```
Setting VUID To:J8
Setting VUID To:E8
Setting VUID To:J8
Setting VUID To:E8
```

Why it is setting value 4 times? and final value that is being stored in localStorage is `E8`

Comment: I show 4 logs for one click?

Comment: Are you sure the DOM-Elements of the Link are not overlapping, so you don't click on every one of them by accident?

Comment: Which button you click, and in which order ? Could you provide a snippet ?

Comment: Sorry for the wild guess but you could also try
onClick={() => {this.addlocalid('J8');}}

Comment: NO, there is basically a table, on every row there is `Link` . so they are not overlapping.

Comment: Here the two rows snippet https://pastebin.com/fkTkZ7Ct @soywod

Comment: Yes. 4 logs for one click. @ToniMichelCaubet

Comment: It worked @niorad , Please add it as answer, I will accept it.  Great thanks buddy. And can you please explain what was the issue?

Comment: yes, @niorad also gave a decent and very correct explanation in his answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

onClick needs a Function, not the result of a function.
When you pass `onClick={howOldIs(tony)}`, you're really passing `onClick={32}`. You need to pass `onClick={howOldIs}`, to tell React what it needs to call.
When you pass `onClick={howOldIs(tony)}`, the functions will be evaluated on page-load, therefore you are getting all 4 console.logs.

The problem is, that you can't really pass arguments this way, so you can help yourself by passing an anonymous inline function, which calls the original function with the argument you specified. `onClick={() => {howOldIs(tony)}`.

Another example from simpler times:

```
myButton.addEventListener('click', howOldIs(tony));
```

Does not do what you probably want to do (unless howOldIs is returning a function itself). So you have to do:

`myButton.addEventListener('click', howOldIs);`

Or, if you need to pass an argument:

`myButton.addEventListener('click', () => {howOldIs(tony)});`

I hope this explanation can help.